# How to block access to a specific website

Tags: linux, unix, firewall, iptables

I'm trying to test a product in two different scenarios - when there is access to Youtube.com and when there isn't.
The product is accessible through the internet, so I tried to block youtube's IP with the iptables.
What did I do?
1. Checked Youtube's ip (through ping) `PING youtube.com`
2. Blocked this ip with iptables `sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d 172.217.164.142 -j DROP`
3. pinged again youtube.com and received `ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted` which looked good.
4. After this, I tried to access Youtube's video through my product's UI, and unfortunately succeeded watching the video.
5. I also tried to  add 127.0.0.1 as `www.youtube.com` to my hosts file in the computer. Not sure if it's helpful...

Can you please help me understand how to block any access to/from Youtube site?
Thanks!!

Comment: YouTube has multiple IP addresses, both ipv6 and ipv4 ones, make sure to block them all, as most http clients are smart enough to always pick the working IP address

Comment: I understood how to test the feature when the customer doesn't have connection to Youtube.com.   
The way was to block the network between my computer and Youtube. 
I added 127.0.0.1 as ```www.youtube.com``` in my hosts file. In this way, my computer didn't have access to youtube.com and was a good candidate for testing.

Comment: do you just mean within a web browser?  if so, I'd just use an Ad-blocker that you've added a (custom) rule to block the whole domain

Answer (score 0):

iptables works out of the box on **Data Link**, **Network** and **Transport** TCP/IP stack.
If you need to block domain names then you need an **Application** layer aware firewall, or a web proxy (IE **Squid**).

If these solutions are oversized for you needs, you can always stick to iptables, but need to script some routine that will periodically query DNS to obtain IPs to block.

I used to perform these kind of blockade for Facebook, and it was quite easy because Facebook had an univocal ASN. Can't tell about Youtube, but since we are talking about Google IMHO **you COULD end up blocking other services (Drive, Gmail etc) as well**.

To retrieve ASN IP list via whois command:

> **/usr/bin/whois -h whois.radb.net '!gAS15169'** #(Youtube ASN, beware, could be more)

Then you just need to loop and properly format the resulting IP list, and make iptables rules for each line, add some logging, put in cron and you are done.